# Using GELF with v0.20.0-preview.7?

Tags: logstash, graylog2

A couple months ago, I installed Graylog2 v0.13.0-rc.1 successfully along with Logstash 1.2.1 to send logs through the dedicated `GELF` output. Everything was working nicely.

Today, I've installed Graylog2 v0.20.0-preview.7 but I can't make GELF work. Once started, Graylog does not listen to the port 12201 which is supposed to be the default GELF listening port. I also tried adding the previous config :

```
use_gelf = true
gelf_listen_address = 0.0.0.0
gelf_listen_port = 12201
```

...but to no avail.

Is there some kind of different configuration for GELF with the 0.20.0-x versions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"You are starting inputs from the web interface now. Go to System -> 
Nodes -> [Action dropdown] -> Manage inputs and start as many GELF 
inputs as you want." - Lennart Koopmann (@_lennart)

For those of you who are interested, my question was answered by Lennart Koopmann (@_lennart) on the Graylog2 google group:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/graylog2/uEyU0IA-O-4/Ni-Zx9NShL8J